# Find All but last duplicate records from MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, row-number

I have a mysql table with following records

```
-------------------------------
| ID | Name | Age | XXX | YYY |
-------------------------------
| 1  | aa   | 12  | qqq | rr  |
-------------------------------
| 2  | aa   | 12  | ttt | pp  |
-------------------------------
| 3  | bb   | 13  | qhq | rr  |
-------------------------------
| 4  | bb   | 13  | pqq | tr  |
-------------------------------
| 5  | bb   | 13  | ql  | jjn |
-------------------------------
```

My requirement is to retrieve all duplicate records with respect to first column apart from the last entry. Currently I tried to retrieve duplicates and that is working fine

```
SELECT Name, Age, XXX, YYY FROM list
INNER JOIN (SELECT Name
           FROM   list
           GROUP  BY Name
           HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1) dup
           ON list.Name = dup.Name;
```

Output is like

```
-------------------------------
| ID | Name | Age | XXX | YYY |
-------------------------------
| 1  | aa   | 12  | qqq | rr  |
-------------------------------
| 2  | aa   | 12  | ttt | pp  |
-------------------------------
| 3  | bb   | 13  | qhq | rr  |
-------------------------------
| 4  | bb   | 13  | pqq | tr  |
-------------------------------
| 5  | bb   | 13  | ql  | jjn |
-------------------------------
```

But I want to remove the last record from the output like

```
-------------------------------
| ID | Name | Age | XXX | YYY |
-------------------------------
| 1  | aa   | 12  | qqq | rr  |
-------------------------------
| 3  | bb   | 13  | qhq | rr  |
-------------------------------
| 4  | bb   | 13  | pqq | tr  |
-------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have timestamp attached in records

Comment: Is there any pk in your table?

Comment: Yes id is available in my table. Which is an auto_increment column

Comment: "Yes id is available in my table. Which is an auto_increment column " Next time include **all** table columns especially a id column.. Most of the time id columns with auto_increment option are needed for stabile query results especially when you need record sorting.

Comment: What's your MySQL version? Use `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: 10.1.19 MariaDB

Comment: @Sush I update my answer you can try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create two new columns in `COUNT` and `Row_number` the result because

1. Get `COUNT` total number by `name` column to get the `MAX` rownumber.
2. use `Row_number` by `name` to get rownumber.
3. To write a condition exclude the last rownumber by `name` from total `count`

If your mysql version support *window function* you can try this code.

make `Row_number` and `COUNT` then remove greater `Row_number` by `Name`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
  select *,
         Row_number() over(partition by Name order by ID) rn,
         COUNT(*) over(partition by Name) totle
  from `list` 
) t1
where rn <> totle
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pveMf1jmHC4FkMQV2AmVzv/1)

**EDIT**

if you have `ID`  auto_increment column and your mysql didn't support *window function* you can try this query.

```
SELECT id,Name,Age,XXX,YYY
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `list` t1 WHERE t.ID >= t1.ID AND t.Name = t1.Name) rn,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `list` t1 WHERE t.Name = t1.Name) totle
  FROM `list` t
) t1 
where rn <> totle
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89c37d/8)

**[Results]**:

```
| id | Name | Age | XXX | YYY |
|----|------|-----|-----|-----|
|  1 |   aa |  12 | qqq |  rr |
|  3 |   bb |  13 | qhq |  rr |
|  4 |   bb |  13 | pqq |  tr |
```

Comment: without a column with auto_increment option or datetime column with on update current_timestamp option this query will **not** guarantee the same output when running the query multiple times.. That is because of the data duplication within the name column and because SQL is a unsorted set of data. The MySQL server can return the "sorted" name column records in **anny** order it wishes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, you right,
If the table didn't an auto_increment `order by` is random, I see that the question has updated information. I also updated my answer.

Comment: It worked as intended. Thank you. Can you add few lines to describe how this query actually works

Comment: @Sush i would also use "`list`" table name in these statements`t.ID >= ID AND t.Name = list.Name` and `WHERE  t.Name = list.Name` so a SQL related server can never mix up the table column names within co-related subqueries if both tables has columns with the same name ..

Comment: @Sush I add some note hope can help you.